# Kill the page from loading feather

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2 and would like to kill the page from feather loading similar to PHP *die();* function

Below is the method that I currently working with.

```
fetch_data() {
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({ content: 'Loading...' });
    loader.present();
    this.bank.types().subscribe( response => {
      this.linkBankTypes = response.results;
      loader.dismiss();
    }, err => {
        loader.dismiss();
        loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({ content: 'No Internet connection. Make sure Wi-Fi or cellular data is turned on, then try again.' });
        //Kill the page from here
    });
  }
```

Comment: you mean nav.pop?

Comment: After `loader.dismiss()`, do you need to present loading again? As I see it a simple alert message would suffice. Also, what do you expect should happen by "kill the page". Here are few options - Navigate to any other page/Navigate to the back page/ simply exit the app/ go to internet settings?

Answer (score 0):

PHP's die() function stops creation of the page and lets PHP run environment to return a nasty error message to the client browser.

You can cause the Ionic to crash by throwing exceptions, but that is not a pleasant user experience and not recommended.

Instead you either navigate to an error page or show a message indicating the error.

The `NavController`'s `push` or `pop`can be used to navigate to an error page or back to the previous page.